# Update UI within a backround thread not working using a Handler

Tags: android

I am new to android.

I am writing a program that download a file from a URL, while busy downloading from the backgroud thread it should update the textview with the current bytes read.

However, in `Log.d("","")` it gets updated immediately but not on `textview(lbStatus)`

I have tried using both the `Handler` and the the `runOnUiThread()` method to run the runnable method.

Can you please assist, your help in this problem will be much appreciated.

DownloadThread class:

```
public class DownloadThread implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        URL myurl = null;
        int read = -1;
        HttpURLConnection httpconn;
        InputStream is = null;
        FileOutputStream ou = null;

        try
        {
            myurl = new URL(fileurl);
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e1)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("mree",""+e1);    
        }

        try {

              URLConnection urlconn =  myurl.openConnection();
              httpconn = (HttpURLConnection)urlconn;
              is = httpconn.getInputStream();
              int len= httpconn.getContentLength();          
              File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+Uri.parse(fileurl).getLastPathSegment());            
              ou = new FileOutputStream(file);
              read = is.read();
              CurrByte = 0;

              myhandler.post(new MainActivity.UpdateS(len));
              //runOnUiThread(new MainActivity.UpdateS(len)) 

              while(read != -1)
              {
                CurrByte++; 
                ou.write(read);
                read = is.read();                   
               }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("mree","Error Message:  "+e);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (is != null)
            {
                try {
                    is.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (ou != null)
            {
              try {
                   ou.close();
                  } 
              catch (IOException e)
               {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
             }
        }


    }

}
```

UpdateS class:

```
public class UpdateS implements Runnable{
        int filelength;
        UpdateS(int len)
        {
            this.filelength = len;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
             TextView lbMessage =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbStatus);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            updateloop:
             for(;;)
            {           
             lbMessage.setText("Bytes read: "+CurrByte);
             Log.d("mree","Bytes read:"+CurrByte);
                try
                {
                  Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
               catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                }

               if(filelength == CurrByte)
               {
                   break updateloop;
               }
            }   
        }

    }
```

MainActivity class:

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
String fileurl = "http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/beautiful_christmas_greeting_card_01_vector_180185.jpg";

Handler myhandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
int CurrByte= 0;
//String fd ="http://www.oracle.com/";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btDownload =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btDownload);
    btDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Thread myThread = new Thread(new DownloadThread());
            myThread.start();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't see usage of Handler nor runOnUIThread() here.

Comment: myhandler.post(new MainActivity.UpdateS(len)), its above the while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this is the problem:

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

You can't block your UI thread, because it won't be updated. Try to remove this. Also, you will probably have to remove `for` loop from `UpdateS` class.

Edit:

The best way would be to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) which is designed specifically to perform background operations and publishing results on UI thread.

Edit2:

Another option, without using `AsyncTasks`:

Your UpdateS class should look like this:

```
public class UpdateS implements Runnable {
    int filelength;
    Activity context;

    UpdateS(int len, Activity context) {
        this.filelength = len;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        TextView lbMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbStatus);
        updateloop: for (;;) {

            context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    lbMessage.setText("Bytes read: " + CurrByte);
                }
            });

            Log.d("mree", "Bytes read:" + CurrByte);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (filelength == CurrByte) {
                break updateloop;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Call in your `DownloadThread` :

```
 myhandler.post(new MainActivity.UpdateS(len, MainActivity.this));
```

Comment: I have removed the Thread.sleep(1000), and it still the Textview gets update after the thread has finished but the Log.d works fine.

Comment: @Mree you should not execute loop in UI thread. See edits for this answer with modified code.